# How to Interpret scatter plot for binary response?

Tags: r, logistic, interpretation, binary-data, scatterplot

I have come to know about scatterplot matrices, where pairwise scatterplots for covariates are built and then binary responses are jittered. This plot is helpful to give an idea about how each covariate has an effect on the response without fitting a logistic regression. But I actually don't understand the plot really. Here is the code that gives this type of plot:

```
library(MASS)
library("ggplot2")

train <- rbind(Pima.tr, Pima.tr2)
train$type <- as.integer(train$type)-1L

library(GGally)

pairs(subset(train, select= - c(type)), col = as.factor(train$type))
```

The red dots are maybe the points where the response is 1. How can I interpret this plot below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find it a little strange that you were taught to use both `ggplot2` and `GGally` but then are forced to use base R plots, but I guess that's a separate issue.

First, it helps to know what was done before this. You have taken two datasets from the `MASS` package (the `Pima.tr` and `Pima.tr2` datasets), bound their rows with `rbind` to make it one dataset, and converted a categorical variable of "type" into a dummy-coded one (using $0$ and $1$ as the coding).

The `pairs` code runs a bunch of scatterplots on whatever numeric data you have (the `subset` function here is used to take out the one variable that isn't because it forces an error if you don't). The `col = as.factor(train$type)` argument basically colors the factors listed, here the factor of "type", and plots them in R. Otherwise you would normally get a bunch of black and white scatterplots. So basically, the plot has colored the previously "Yes" or "No" type data into black and red so you can differentiate the two.

Since you are already working with `GGally`, you can create a `ggplot2` version with the following code (though this version replaces the redundant scatter plots on the upper triangle/diagonal of the matrix with density plots and correlations).

```
#### GGally Version ####
p <- ggpairs(train,
              columns = 1:7,
              ggplot2::aes(color=as.factor(type)))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","red"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","red"))
p
```

[image]

##### Edit

I realize I flew past the actual explanation of the plots as I wrote this answer in a rush awhile back. To summarize, the scatter plots (those which have a bunch of data points), show the association between two variables. The closer they cluster together (the more they resemble a straight line), the more associated they are with each other. The colors of the data points simply express how this association looks between different factors. The names on the diagonal and the axes are simply the names of the variables. You match each diagonal name with each axis name to see which variables are plotted against each other.

My specific plot adds to that with the inclusion of density plots, which simply show the distribution of each variable by itself. Higher peaks represent a larger amount of data located in that region of the distribution. The shape of the distribution can be particularly useful for understanding what you are doing in inferential tests.

Comment: Nice graphs and sweet explanation of R +1 :-)
Maybe OP wanted to know what the results mean for their analysis? Who knows...

Comment: Ah yes sorry about that. I wrote this in a rush awhile back. I've edited with clarity.

Comment: Another +1 if I could :-)